# Express JS routing based authentication

Tags: node.js, express

I have created node js app using express framework.

I have created middleware for restricting access to some routes.

Middleware actually works fine. but i have difficulties in displaying data.

Suppose In My app i have created route for display list of countries('/country/master')i.e html page  which is using internally different/default route ('/country/') to get data from mongoDB.

In this case user will not able to see data cause i have not given permission to "/" routes. but i want to display data but not allow him to make use of "/" route to check data.

How can i deal with this case ????

Comment: what do you mean by make use of? if you mean you want to prohibit someone for posting data, you can use middleware for post only. like... `app.post('/', yourRestrictionFunction)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on your authentication strategy i.e. are you using session identifiers, access tokens, etc.

In either case I suggest that you break out the credential exchange (aka login) from the authentication.  They should be separate middleware functions.  Below is an example of what this looks like.

While this answers your question, specific to ExpressJS, it does leave out a lot of other details that matter when you are building an authentication system (like how to securely store passwords).  I work at [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com), we provide user management as an API so that you don't have to worry about all the security details!  It's very easy to integrate our API into your application, using the [express-stormpath](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-express) module.  You'll have a fully featured user database in minutes, without having to setup mongo or a user table.

All that said, here's the example:

```
/* pseudo example of building your own authentication middleware */

function usernamePasswordExchange(req,res,next){
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;

  callToAuthService(username,password,function(err,user){
    if(err){
      next(err); // bad password, user doesn’t exist, etc
    }else{
      /*
        this part depends on your application.  do you use
        sessions or access tokens?  you need to send the user
        something that they can use for authentication on
        subsequent requests
      */
      res.end(/* send something */);
    }
  });
}

function authenticate(req,res,next){
  /*
    read the cookie, access token, etc.
    verify that it is legit and then find
    the user that it’s associated with
  */
  validateRequestAndGetUser(req,function(err,user){
    if(err){
      next(err); // session expired, tampered, revoked
    }else{
      req.user = user;
      next();
    }
  });
}

app.post('/login',usernamePasswordExchange);

app.get('/protected-resource',authenticate,function(req,res,next){
  /*
    If we are here we know the user is authenticated and we
    can know who the user is by referencing req.user
  */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can positioning of middleware in you app.for example:-

```
app.get('/country/master',function(req,res){

})

app.use(function(req,res){
  your middle ware for providing authentication
})

// other routes where authentication should be enabled
app.get('other urls')
```

Comment: i have route "/country/master" which is my html view and "/country/"is default api to get data. which is required for my app to get data and i need when user tries to hit on above url from browser he should be restricted

Comment: @Overseas634 are u trying to say /country/master is route which gives html page as response.

Comment: yes '/country/master' is route which gives html page as response

Comment: @Overseas634 than you can try above code.let me know if it does not works.

Comment: I  am doing authentication like this" router.get('/master',authentication ,function(req, res, next){}); and it is working fine

Comment: @Overseas634 i think you should use middleware because for authentication because will save you from rewriting code like i did in above example and also if you want client to access urls with no authentication than u can write those urls above middleware.